# List files in sub-directories with QDir's filter

Tags: c++, qt, glob, qtcore, qdir

I'm looking for a function similar to the python glob function.

```
If my folder structure is:
folder1/abc1.txt
folder1/xyz1.txt
folder1/abc2.txt
folder2/abc3.txt
folder2/xyz4.txt
folder3/abc5.txt
```

then if I give `*/abc*`, I'm looking for an output of:

```
folder1/abc1.txt
folder1/abc2.txt
folder2/abc3.txt
folder3/abc5.txt
```

I tried entrylist, but it just lets me filter on what's in the current folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can of course traverse recursively with an embedded loop like this:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QDir>
#include <QFileInfoList>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>

void traverse(const QString &pattern, const QString &dirname, int level)
{
    QDir dir(dirname);
    dir.setFilter(QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks | QDir::NoDot | QDir::NoDotDot);

    static const QStringList stringList = pattern.split('/');
    foreach (QFileInfo fileInfo, dir.entryInfoList(stringList.mid(level, 1))) {
        if (fileInfo.isDir() && fileInfo.isReadable())
            traverse(pattern, fileInfo.filePath(), level+1);
        else if (stringList.size() == (level + 1))
            qDebug() << fileInfo.filePath();
    }
}

int main()
{
    traverse("*/abc*", ".", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
"./folder1/abc1.txt"
"./folder1/abc2.txt"
"./folder2/abc3.txt"
"./folder3/abc5.txt"
```

Comment: yes, I could do that, or use entry list then filter manually.  I wanted to know if there was a single function that would do it similar to glob.

Comment: @eng3: this _is_ the single function that does that. This function is not written in Qt if that is what you are after.

Answer (score -1):

for those using the new version of QT

my suggestion would be, use the [qdirEntryList][1]:

1. set the root to `root_directory`
2. then search all the images using a filter(png, jpj or what you need) and
3. then generate a pseudo random number between 0 and `list.size()` and
4. use that as index for getting the path of the image,
5. that finally you will use in the constructor of the `QImage` Object you are going to return.